# Microsoft Graph subscriptions can't monitor recurring events instances

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

So I have been building my API to use the Microsoft Graph Subscriptions to read the events of a resource mailbox calendar.
Everything seems to work, the only issue is that when you work with recurring events then all of a sudden you can't check the instances.
As it only returns the id of the master event for that recurring series, while the update wasn't applied to the master but an instance of that recurring series.
Especially when you try to delete an instance of the series no matter how far you delete it in the future it will always send a notification for the entire series, making it kinda impossible to know what instances got deleted...

Any ideas how to handle recurring events with subscriptions perfectly?
Cause I'm kinda getting clueless on how to process this accordingly.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Billy

PS: I also added it on: [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1445179/microsoft-graph-subscriptions-cant-monitor-recurri)